# Selenium -Extracting data from excel and writing to web page -Issues in program

Tags: excel, selenium

I am trying to extract data from excel and write it to a web page . As I click on a drop down"I am " provided in the link in the code below  the remaining contents of the page changes .I have made certain cells as blank.I wrote the code but getting some exceptions .Please help

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Copyprogram {
    public static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        driver.get("http://www.deal4loans.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/a[1]")).click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        try {

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Copy of  Booklet1.xlsx");

            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                  XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("testdata");
            // Loop through all rows in the sheet
            // Start at row 1 as row 0 is our header row

       int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
            for(int i = 1;i<=rowCount;i++)
                {

                 Row row1 = sheet.getRow(i);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                // TODO: handle exception
                }

                runTest(row1.getCell(1).toString(),row1.getCell(2).toString(),row1.getCell(3).toString(),row1.getCell(4).toString(),row1.getCell(5).toString(),row1.getCell(6).toString(),row1.getCell(7).toString(),row1.getCell(8).toString(),row1.getCell(9).toString(),row1.getCell(10).toString(),row1.getCell(11).toString(),row1.getCell(12).toString(),row1.getCell(13).toString() );

                System.out.println(row1.getCell(1).toString());
                System.out.println(row1.getCell(2).toString());
                System.out.println(row1.getCell(3).toString());
                System.out.println(row1.getCell(4).toString());
                System.out.println(row1.getCell(5).toString());
                System.out.println(row1.getCell(6).toString());
                System.out.println(row1.getCell(7).toString());
                System.out.println(row1.getCell(8).toString());
                System.out.println(row1.getCell(9).toString());
                System.out.println(row1.getCell(10).toString());

               if (i<rowCount)
               {
                driver.navigate().back();
            }

                System.out.println(i);
                }
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Test data file not found");
        }   

        driver.close();

    }

    public static  void runTest(String name,String mailid,String query,String city,String mob,String pdt,String PL,String HL,String CL,String LA,String BL,String CC,String ass) 
    {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(name);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(mailid);

    Select listbox1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select")));
      listbox1.selectByValue(query);

      String selectedValue =listbox1.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();

           Select listbox2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/select")));
       listbox2.selectByValue(city);

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(mob);
     if (selectedValue=="1")
     {

       Select listbox3 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/select")));
       listbox3.selectByValue(pdt);

     }

     else

     {
         if (PL == null && PL.length() == 0)
         {
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=PL]")).click();
      System.out.println(PL);
         }


        if(HL == null && HL.length() == 0)
        {

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=HL]")).click();

        }

        if(CL == null && CL.length() == 0)
        {

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=CL]")).click();
        }
        if(LA == null && LA.length() == 0)
        {
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=LA]")).click();
        }
        if(BL == null && BL.length() == 0)
        {

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=BL]")).click();

        }

        if(CC== null && CC.length() == 0)
        {
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=CC]")).click();
     }
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(ass);


     }
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[9]/td/input")).click();

    }
    }
```

Comment: what exact issue you are getting? in which field and what error you getting?

Comment: Since the excel has blank cells when the first option is selected  ,program is unable to handle those and I get exception in main fn

Comment: please add below code after your for loop :                               Cell c = row1.getCell(i, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL); then put condition if(row1 == null) { //skip } else { get data }